# How to make a job step work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, jobs

This code works when run as SQL Query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 but when is set as Job step then works only second condition (update when is not last day of month). What is wrong with this code?

```
 --set next invoice date
    declare @data nvarchar(10) --invoice date
    set @data = CONVERT (date, GETDATE());

    update table 
    set invoice_date = case when day(DATEADD(day,1,@data)) = 1 then --is last day of month
                                    (SELECT convert(date,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))) -- set inovice date as last day of next month
                          else --is not last day of month
                                    (select DATEADD(MM,1,@data)) --add one month to inovice date
                            end
    where status = 'current' and invoice_date = @data  -- only for current inovices
```

Comment: On which time you are running the SQL Job?

Comment: Job occures every day at 23:00:00.

Comment: (SELECT convert(date,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))) -- set inovice date as last day of next month . In this code you mentioned like last day of next month. but its taking last day of current month.

Comment: @GuruprakashC thanks a lot! Scenerio was: on 2016-09-30 jobs run script. Script set end of current month date (script should set end of next month but didn't). On 2016-10-01 user got wrong date (2016-09-30) so he run script from Management Studio and script set again current end of month date (2016-10-31).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First condition will work on every month last day only.

```
--set next invoice date
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(10) --invoice date
SET @data = CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE());

UPDATE table 
SET invoice_date = CASE WHEN DAY(DATEADD(DAY,1,@data)) = 1 
                   THEN --is last day of month
                      CAST( DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@data)+2,0)) AS DATE) -- set inovice date as last day of next month
                   ELSE --is not last day of month
                     (DATEADD(MM,1,@data)) --add one month to inovice date
                        END
WHERE status = 'current' AND invoice_date = @data  -- only for current inovices
```